# How to use url in collections in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Am not able to access my xml file which is inside js folder thru the url function inside collections.How to link to this url to retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've setted up the path to your file, you'll have to call fetch on the collection. like so:

```
var Things = backbone.Collection.extend({ url: "path/to/my/file" });
var things = new Things();
things.fetch().done(function() {
  console.log( things.toJSON() );
});
```

Although, this only works with JSON data format. For XML, you'll need to override [collection's `parse` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse) to return a javascript object from the XML.

Comment: {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
  "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
   "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
     "SortAs": "SGML",
     "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
     "Acronym": "SGML",
     "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
     "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
      "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
     "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}have to stringify

Comment: i tried wat u said but am not able to do it my path is url: "C:/Users/E808514/Desktop/demo/demo/js/tree.json"

Comment: You need to host your backbone application on some server (localhost). Backbone can not load files from file system, but only from a URL.